# Crazy long "exception occurred" while installing version 5.7.2.1 of CMS Concrete5

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, concrete5, concrete

I finally almost have Concrete5 installed on my website, I am using GoDaddy hosted on Linux OS, with PHP version 5.3.

The link to my installation page I am stuck on (that displays the error) is: 
http://texasca.com/blog/concrete5.7.2.1/index.php/install

The error thrown is:

```
    An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO FileStorageLocationTypes 

    (fslTypeHandle, fslTypeName, pkgID) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params ["default", "Default", 0]: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'default' for key 'fslTypeHandle'.

    Trace:
    #0 /home/content/31/11023231/html/blog/concrete5.7.2.1/concrete/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php(167): Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException::driverExceptionDuringQuery(Object(PDOException), 'INSERT INTO Fil...', Array) #1
 /home/content/31/11023231/html/blog/concrete5.7.2.1/concrete/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php(279): Doctrine\DBAL\Statement->execute() #2
 /home/content/31/11023231/html/blog/concrete5.7.2.1/concrete/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php(966): Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister->executeInserts() #3
 /home/content/31/11023231/html/blog/concrete5.7.2.1/concrete/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php(335): Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->executeInserts(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata)) #4
 /home/content/31/11023231/html/blog/concrete5.7.2.1/concrete/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php(389): Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->commit(NULL) #5
 /home/content/31/11023231/html/blog/concrete5.7.2.1/concrete/src/File/StorageLocation/Type/Type.php(93): Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->flush() #6 /home/content/31/11023231/html/blog/concrete5.7.2.1/concrete/src/Package/StartingPointPackage.php(149): Concrete\Core\File\StorageLocation\Type\Type::add('default', 'Default') #7
 [internal function]: Concrete\Core\Package\StartingPointPackage->import_files() #8
 /home/content/31/11023231/html/blog/concrete5.7.2.1/concrete/controllers/install.php(282): call_user_func(Array) #9 [internal function]: Concrete\Controller\Install->run_routine('elemental_full', 'import_files') #10
 /home/content/31/11023231/html/blog/concrete5.7.2.1/concrete/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(156): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #11
 /home/content/31/11023231/html/blog/concrete5.7.2.1/concrete/src/Routing/ControllerRouteCallback.php(25): Concrete\Core\Controller\AbstractController->runAction('run_routine', Array) #12 /home/content/31/11023231/html/blog/concrete5.7.2.1/concrete/src/Routing/Router.php(59): Concrete\Core\Routing\ControllerRouteCallback->execute(Object(Concrete\Core\Http\Request), Object(Concrete\Core\Routing\Route), Array) #13
 /home/content/31/11023231/html/blog/concrete5.7.2.1/concrete/src/Support/Facade/Facade.php(116): Concrete\Core\Routing\Router->execute(Object(Concrete\Core\Routing\Route), Array) #14
 /home/content/31/11023231/html/blog/concrete5.7.2.1/concrete/src/Application/Application.php(340): Concrete\Core\Support\Facade\Facade::__callStatic('execute', Array) #15
 /home/content/31/11023231/html/blog/concrete5.7.2.1/concrete/src/Application/Application.php(340): Concrete\Core\Support\Facade\Route::execute(Object(Concrete\Core\Routing\Route), Array) #16
 /home/content/31/11023231/html/blog/concrete5.7.2.1/concrete/bootstrap/start.php(196): Concrete\Core\Application\Application->dispatch(Object(Concrete\Core\Http\Request)) #17
 /home/content/31/11023231/html/blog/concrete5.7.2.1/concrete/dispatcher.php(36): require('/home/content/3...') #18
 /home/content/31/11023231/html/blog/concrete5.7.2.1/index.php(2): require('/home/content/3...') #19 {main}
```

Its pretty intimidating error to understand and fix because it is so long and I am no expert at SQL or installing CMS frameworks like Concrete5. All I did was have GoDaddy create a blank MySQL 5.5 Database with its database creator tool.

What am I doing wrong? I hope this is just a noob problem. Please help!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment yet as I have low reputation, but I think this is to do with your site.php file which is located within your config directory. This usually brings up errors to do with SQL in the early stages of concrete5 installation.

Check that your site.php matches up with your SQL on the Go Daddy control panel

```
<?php
define('CACHE_FRONTEND_OPTIONS', serialize(array('automatic_cleaning_factor' => 0)));
define('DB_SERVER', 'example');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'example');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'example.');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'example');
```

Best of luck

Comment: OK I am going to go check on that! I'll let you know if that helps, thanks

Comment: no luck - the site.php file I found was under concrete\single_pages\dashboard\system\permissions and had none of the code you mentioned. Maybe you were using an earlier release than I was and they have changed the name of that file?

Comment: @ZachCook All Concrete5 sites must have a site.php. You were looking in the incorrect place. Its in the top directory under/config/site.php

Comment: well we have a serious problem then, because I found a site.php file but it was in a different location. the php files there are (1) app.php (2) concrete.php and (3) database.php

Comment: I'm probably going to just switch to a Javascript based CMS like KeystoneJS - cuz this is bs